# QuickSort out of bounds

Tags: c++, quicksort

I've made a vector class implement the quicksort algorithm:

```
class myVector{
//...
private:
    T* ptr;//the array
    void quick_sort(int low, int high,bool(*compare_func)(const T& left, const T& right)) {
        if (low < high) {
            int pi = partition(low, high,compare_func);
            quick_sort(low, pi - 1,compare_func);
            quick_sort(pi + 1, high,compare_func);
        }
    }
    int partition(int low, int high,,bool(*compare_func)(const T& left, const T& right)) {
        const T& pivot = ptr[high];
        int i = low - 1;

        for (int j = low; j <= high - 1; j++) {
            if (compare_func(ptr[j], pivot)) {
                i++;
                std::swap(ptr[i], ptr[j]);
            }
        }
        std::swap(ptr[i + 1], ptr[high]);
        return i + 1;
    }
};
```

the compare function looks like this:

```
    myVector<float> myArray;
    //...
    bool compare(const float& left,const float& right) {
        return right > left;
    }
```

it works fine when the size of the vector is small,like 1000 or so.But the program start to quit with error code when I increase the vector's size to around 10000.
I've tried to change the

`for (int j = low; j <= high - 1; j++)`
to
`for (int j = low; j <= high - 2; j++)`

and the program runs normally,but as the size of the vector get around 100000,error code appears again.
Is there anybody know where I do it wrong?Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: Randomly twiddling offsets is not really debugging, it's more like poking at something dead with a stick and hoping magic happens. Try and work this out on paper to be sure you're implementing it correctly. Verify all those offsets very carefully. Off-by-one errors are frustrating and easy to make.

Comment: Don't say "error code appears" without telling us what the error is exactly, and where it appears (simply running the code in a debugger will instantly tell you where).

Comment: Your two calls to quicksort have a gap at the pivot. Not good.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Can you tell us what kind of error do you get?

Comment: @HikmatFarhat it's says "Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF70A3423BA in quicksort.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x0000000000000001)"  at if (compare_func(ptr[j], pivot)) {

Comment: @dsukrect As i said your code is fine. I suspect the problem is how it is called. Can you post how quicksort is called? In particular since you are choosing the the last element as the pivot there might a problem there since usually you pass an half open interval i.e. begin() to end()

Comment: myVector<float> data; data.sort(0,data.size(),compare_function);

Comment: @dsukrect it should be 0 to data.size() -1 no?

Comment: sorry I forgot to post this: void sort(int offset, int n, bool(*compare_func)(const T& left, const T& right)) {
  quick_sort(offset, offset + n - 1, compare_func);
 };

Comment: I believe it would be easier if you could provide us with a [mre]. Are you able to reliably reproduce the error if you generated the to be sorted numbers algorithmically? You might want to consider using the funciton `rand` to generate the numbers, if that is the only way to reproduce the error.